# Using a pointer to an array of structs does not return the complete array

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have a main program that is supposed to receive as result of calling a function to load data (array of structs, undefined size), the proper data and then continuing processing it.

Following is a little example of what I'm trying to do. The function `loadData` receives a pointer to the main pointer, so that the main pointer may be assigned a portion of memory through `malloc`. The data is loaded and printed within the `loadData` function. But when it returns to main it only shows a correct content for the first item of the array of structures. The second item is garbage.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{ 
    int dni;
    char cat;
    int weight;
} boxers;

void loadData(boxers *(*xbox), int *xcount)
{
    printf("How many boxers? ");
    scanf("%d", xcount);

    *xbox = (boxers *) malloc(sizeof(boxers) * (*xcount));

    for (int i = 0; i < (*xcount); i++)
    {
        printf("Provide the DNI for boxer number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &xbox[i]->dni);
        printf("Provide the Category for boxer number %d: ", i);
        scanf(" %c", &xbox[i]->cat);
        printf("Provide the Weight for boxer number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &xbox[i]->weight);
    }

    // First print the result of data loading
    for (int i = 0; i < *xcount; i++)
    {
        printf("DNI for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, xbox[i]->dni);
        printf("Category for boxer number %d, is: %c \n", i, xbox[i]->cat);
        printf("Weight for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, xbox[i]->weight);
    }

}

int main()
{
    boxers *box;
    int count;

    loadData(&box, &count);

    // Second print the result of data loading
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("DNI for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, box[i].dni);
        printf("Category for boxer number %d, is: %c \n", i, box[i].cat);
        printf("Weight for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, box[i].weight);
    }

    free(box);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The console output is the following:

```
How many boxers? 2
Provide the DNI for boxer number 0: 123
Provide the Category for boxer number 0: A
Provide the Weight for boxer number 0: 45
Provide the DNI for boxer number 1: 789
Provide the Category for boxer number 1: B
Provide the Weight for boxer number 1: 56

DNI for boxer number 0, is: 123
Category for boxer number 0, is: A
Weight for boxer number 0, is: 45
DNI for boxer number 1, is: 789
Category for boxer number 1, is: B
Weight for boxer number 1, is: 56


DNI for boxer number 0, is: 123
Category for boxer number 0, is: A
Weight for boxer number 0, is: 45
DNI for boxer number 1, is: 7471203
Category for boxer number 1, is: x
Weight for boxer number 1, is: 7536756
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&xbox[i]->dni` is wrong. The return value from `malloc` was assigned to `*xbox`, so `*xbox` points to the memory, and `xbox` points to that that pointer.

So the memory is at `*xbox`. The first structure there is `**xbox` or, equivalently, `(*xbox)[0]`. The next structure is `(*xbox)[1]`, and so on. So you want `(*xbox)[i]` for the structure with index `i`. Then, since that is a structure, not a pointer to it, you want `.dni`, not `->dni`. So that member is `(*xbox)[i].dni`. Then its address is `&(*xbox)[i].dni`.

In contrast, since `xbox` is a pointer to a pointer, then `xbox[0]` is that pointer, and `xbox[1]` would be the pointer after that. But there is no pointer after that; `xbox` just points to a single pointer. So `xbox[i]` is wrong.

The same change is needed in the other member references in the routine.

To avoid this easy-to-make mistake, in routines where a pointer-to-a-pointer is passed, a local pointer may be defined to make references easier:

```
void loadData(boxers **xbox, int *xcount)
{
    …
    boxers *p = *xbox = malloc(xcount * sizeof *p);
    …
        scanf("%d", &p[i]->dni);
    …
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Both yours and Vlad's are pointing the right issue with the original code. It is very clear and now I understand what was wrong with my interpretation of the pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 2):

These assignments

```
for (int i = 0; i < (*xcount); i++)
{
    printf("Provide the DNI for boxer number %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &xbox[i]->dni);
    printf("Provide the Category for boxer number %d: ", i);
    scanf(" %c", &xbox[i]->cat);
    printf("Provide the Weight for boxer number %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &xbox[i]->weight);
}
```

are incorrect. You have to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < (*xcount); i++)
{
    printf("Provide the DNI for boxer number %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &( *xbox )[i].dni);
    printf("Provide the Category for boxer number %d: ", i);
    scanf(" %c", &( *xbox )[i].cat);
    printf("Provide the Weight for boxer number %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &( *xbox )[i].weight);
}
```

and then

```
for (int i = 0; i < *xcount; i++)
{
    printf("DNI for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, ( *xbox )[i].dni);
    printf("Category for boxer number %d, is: %c \n", i, ( *xbox )[i].cat);
    printf("Weight for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, ( *xbox )[i].weight);
}
```

Compare the above loop with this loop in main

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    printf("DNI for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, box[i].dni);
    printf("Category for boxer number %d, is: %c \n", i, box[i].cat);
    printf("Weight for boxer number %d, is: %d \n", i, box[i].weight);
}
```

The difference is that in main the pointer `box` has the type `boxers *` while in the function the pointer `xbox` has the type `boxers **`. So you need at first to dereference the pointer in the function like `( *xbox )` and then to apply the subscript operator as you are doing in main as for example `( *xbox )[i].weight`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Both yours and Eric's are pointing the right issue with the original code. It is very clear and now I understand what was wrong with my interpretation of the pointer to pointer.